# Most pythonic way to call functions already available in global namespace

Tags: python, function, pytest

I'm currently setting up a test suite for a file called `main.py`. The test file is called `test_main.py`. Here's an example:

```
# main.py
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
```

```
#test_main.py
import pytest
from main import *

def test_add():
    assert add(1,2) == 3
```

For reasons which are outside the scope of this question, I would like to *dynamically* load the function `add` in `test_main.py` as opposed to calling it directly. I'm already aware this is possible using the following

- `globals` or `vars`
- use of `importlib`
- use of `eval`

However, I'd like to see if there's another option. `globals` and `vars` are bad practice. `eval` is allright, but it doesn't return the function object and I have to do some string manipulation to get the function call, including its arguments right. `importlib` is by far the best option, but `main.py` happens to contain functions which I want to import the "normal" way. It feels wrong to import functions in `test_main.py` using both an `import` statement and the `importlib` module.

So, is there a better way? One which is more pythonic?

Comment: My initial reaction is that dynamically loading functions feels unpythonic to begin with.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad as a starting point for why 'from main import *' is poor practice

Comment: I've seen many established open source codebases that make extensive use of things like `getattr` which are in essence dynamically extracting bits and pieces of already instantiated classes

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp Ok that I understand and agree with. However, since I'm not actually making a package for the moment (just refactoring some legacy VBA code), I think its OK to get away with `from x import *`, since the code will probably change enormously along the way anyway.

Comment: Perhaps you might find https://realpython.com/python-import/#using-importlib useful?